# Why does $x^Ty x = xx^Ty = Ay$ make intuitive sense?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, intuition

Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$

Then it is clear

$$x^Ty x = xx^Ty$$

Call $$xx^T  = A$$

Then we have $$x^Ty x = Ay$$

Something struck me as unintuitive, because the left-hand side did not involve a matrix term, but the right handside does. All the algebra works out.

Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: The eigenvalue equation, $A x = \lambda x$ also involves multiplication by a matrix on one side of the equation and multiplication by a scalar on the other side.  This is okay because both sides evaluate to a vector.

Comment: @mjw this is good intuition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the source of your intuition problems is that $x^\top y x$ is, strictly speaking, an abuse of notation. If $x$ and $y$ are column vectors in $\Bbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, then the matrix multiplication $x^\top y x$ is not sensible, as $yx$ is not a sensible matrix multiplication: we cannot multiply two $n \times 1$ matrices. Or, similarly, $(x^\top y)$ is a $1 \times 1$ matrix, which cannot be multiplied to the $n \times 1$ matrix $x$.

Of course, the intention is for you to treat $x^\top y$ as a scalar, rather than a $1 \times 1$ matrix, in which case, writing it in front of the matrix $x$ is par for the course. But, if you don't make such a concession, then the only sensible way to scale the $n \times 1$ matrix $x$ by the one and only entry of $x^\top y$ is to multiply it on the end, i.e. $x(x^\top y)$.

So, the mystery commutativity we see in $x^\top y x = xx^\top y$ is not really a commutativity of matrix multiplication. The left hand side involves a different type of multiplication: scalar multiplication, and should really be written as $(x^\top y)_{11}x$.